# Sklearn regression problem

Tags: scikit-learn

I try to fit a data matrix X to an output vector y with a regression model in sklearn. I have some training data and some test data, where the score is the RMSE.

So my best score I achieved with SVR, kernel 'poly' and tuning the hyperparameters 'C', 'degree' and 'gamma' with optunity and cross-validation.

I actually don't know how to achieve better scores so I ask here in this forum for another approach. I tried already KernelRidge, Linear Regression, SVR with other kernels, Neural Networks but all of them gave worse results. It is actually possible to do better, since other people do better in this task, but I have no more Idea what I can do to imporve the score. Any Ideas?

Comment: Data pre-processing and feature extraction are the most important aspect of a machine learning architecture, NOT THE MODEL. Can you give us more information about the dataset? Size? Features?

Comment: Well, actually there is no feature extraction, since the data matrix is already given. Pre-processing I did not yet, but I have really not much knowledge in this topic. I think I will read a bit about it. The Dataset is a 2000x25 matrix.

Comment: Even if the data is already given to you, that is raw data. From the raw data you should be able to remold it to better suit your needs. Moreover, you should always use some feature extraction technique. I will post some kind of answer.

Comment: What are the 25 features?

Comment: The feature vectors consists just of numbers, I don't have an background information about the problem.

Comment: There are no headers for what the features are. What do the numbers represent? If you really have no information then you should start with viewing the distribution of the features and the cross-correlation between the features.

Answer (score 0):

Data pre-processing and feature extraction are the two most important parts of a machine learning technique. That's right, NOT THE MODEL. If you have good features then even a very simple model will get amazing results.

Data pre-processing goes from your raw data and remolds it to be better suited to machine learning algorithms. This means pulling out important statistics from your data or converting your data into other formats in order to it being more representative. For example if you are using a technique which is sensitive to range, then you should normalize all your features. If you are using text data you should build word vectors. There are countless ways pre-processing and feature extraction can be implemented.

Then, you want to use feature selection. From all the information you extracted from your data not all of it will be useful. There are machine learning algorithms such as: PCA, LDA, cross-correlation, etc. Which will select the features that are the most representative and ignore the rest.

Comment: What do you recommend to use for scaling the data matrix when using regression? The preprocessing library in sklearn seems to be only for calssificaion? When I use things like StandardScaler etc. I get very bad results. Btw. the best results are achieved by a polynomial of degree 3.

Comment: I'm always down for LDA even for regression problems. Check out this paper for some other ideas: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/597a/541c28c7e68a29fe6edf13d0741a6a3e6cc7.pdf